# How can I extract Graph generated by excel in java using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, extract

I have an excel that generates a chart based on the data provided.
So I tried using XSSFChart object but was unable to convert it into a byte array.

So does anyone have any idea on how to extract Chart from excel sheet using apache-poi

Implementation done until now:

```
XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)worksheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

            for(XSSFChart chart : drawing.getCharts()){
                    chart // need to convert this chart into byte[]
            }
```

Comment: It would help you to post what you tried, especially since you said you did actually already try it.  Then it will be easier for people to help you on where you went wrong.

Comment: @Nexevis I have added the same

Comment: `XSSFChart` is a `Java` class which is used to describe the structure of a chart in `Office Open XML`. So the `chart` in your code is a `Java` object containing that structure. What do you mean with "to convert this chart into byte[]"? What should the byte array contain?

Comment: @AlexRichter my primary objective is to retrieve the Chart object created by my excel and convert it into byte[]. So do you have any idea on how to accomplish it??

Comment: Again: What should the byte array contain? What you want to do with that byte array then?

Comment: @AlexRichter I want the byte[] of the Chart image data so that I can send it to a frontend screen.

Comment: Then please clarify your question. Your question should clearly state that you want the image data of the `XSSFChart` from `Excel` file. A `XSSFChart` does not provide any image data. And `apache poi` does not provide any rendering of charts. So this will only be possible using other chart rendering libraries like `JFreeChart` for example.

Comment: @AxelRichter Is there a way to extract XSSFChart object and send it as a response to frontend so that they can display it??

Comment: `XSSFChart` does not implement `Serializable`. So no, there is no general way to serialize the entire `XSSFChart` object. But the main part of the `XSSFChart` is `Office Open XML`. And this, of course, could be sent to a frontend. But the frontend would must be able parsing that `XML` properly and rendering a chart image from it. I don't know any free `Java` library which is able to do so. So the only way I would see is reading the data out of the  `XSSFChart` and then creating a new chart from that data using a `Java` chart rendering library like `JFreeChart`.